# how to refresh the rails cache in the parent process without restarting the project in passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, passenger

I have a list of switches in a file and 
I need to maintain those values in the memory. I cant use external cache store like memcache, redis. I am not using ruby enterprise edition either.

This is how i am doing it now

```
#load the cache when the project is starting
MYCACHE =  ActiveSupport::Cache::MemoryStore.new
MYCACHE.write('myswitch', File.read('/tmp/switch'))

#run this when a passenger instance is created, by declaring in environment.rb
begin
  PhusionPassenger.on_event(:starting_worker_process) do |forked|
    if forked
        MYCACHE.write('myswitch', File.read('/tmp/switches.json'))
    end
  end
rescue
end
```

so whenever i change the switch in the file, i do 
`sudo passenger-status --verbose`
and refresh the current instances by hitting their ports and new instances will get refreshed by the on_event(:starting_worker_process) call by reloading the file to the memory

what i am actually looking for is to refresh the parent process from which instances are spawned so that i avoid this block everytime the instance is created.

is there anyway i can achieve this without restarting the project.

Thanks in advance.